# "Save Map As Image" in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis-3

In QGIS 3.0.x, there was a menu

```
Project -> Save Map As Image
```

which allows one to export a portion of the current view (screen shot) into a `png` file at a given dpi.

It is quite convenient, but it seems to be missing in QGIS 3.2.0-Bonn (revision bc43194)

Is it moved to somewhere else from the `Project` menu or removed/disabled/hidden?

How do I get the equivalent function or re-enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the menu after a little exploration.

It seems that the "`Save Map As Image`" is now under `Project -> Import/Export` and called

```
Export Map to Image ...
```

Answer (score 0):

QGIS vs 3.3

- Project; Import/Export; Export map to image/pdf/dxf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).